# Repositories links not working yum.conf in CentOS 6

Tags: gcc, centos, yum

I am running a linux server using RedHat and Centos 6.4

I need to install gcc onto the server, so I have been trying to use yum to install gcc for me, however I seem to have a bit of an issue with installing and updating packages using yum due to the yum.conf file.

If I open my current yum.conf file, I see the following code:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
pkgpolicy=newest
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1

[base]
name=Red Hat Linux $releasever - $basearch - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/$releasever/$basearch/


[updates]
name=Red Hat Linux $releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/updates/$releasever/
```

and whenever I try to run a yum command - for example, "yum update" I get the following errors in my terminal:

```
[root@SERVER etc]# yum update
Gathering header information file(s) from server(s)
Server: Red Hat Linux 6 - x86_64 - Base
retrygrab() failed for:
  http://mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/6/x86_64/headers/header.info
  Executing failover method
failover: out of servers to try
Error getting file http://mirror.dulug.duke.edu/pub/yum-repository/redhat/6/x86_64/headers/header.info
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error >
[root@SERVER etc]#
```

I believe this is due to some old yum mirrors being down, however I cannot find any reference to a proper set of repositories to use in my yum.conf file which would work on CentOS 6.4

The question is: does anybody know where I can find a set of repositories that will work in this scenario? I know that the Yum website is now found at http://yum.baseurl.org/ however I cannot see anything clear with regard to what repositories I should be putting in my yum.conf file..

I am obviously a linux newbie, so if I am missing something important, flame me gently...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a mix of CentOS and RedHat bits. Delete whatever you added. CentOS is easy (examples below). For RedHat if you aren't a registered machine you'll want to use the DVD ISO as source (baseurl=file:///media) or maybe attach to a public EPEL.

Here's a CentOS /etc/yum.conf.

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=16&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum distroverpkg=centos-release
```

And then you should have a few repos that already exist in /etc/yum.repos.d (base/debuginfo/media/vault). Hers's /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Contrib
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```